# What happens when ball touches net during serving?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, serve

I found some information on rules, but I never found a clear answer to what should be done when a served ball touches the net.
Is it point for opponent, or should the serve be redone?
If redone - will it be redone regardless of how many times it hit the net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the serve touches the net, it is a let, and you must serve again. If it touches the net and lands on the floor, you lose a point. If the serve goes into the net, you lose the point.

Comment: It is redone regardless of how many times you hit the net as long as it lands in play.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [USATT Rules](http://www.usatt.org/rules/index.shtml)

> 2.9 A Let
>
> 2.9.1 The rally shall be a let
>
> 2.9.1.1 if in service the ball, in  passing over or around the net  assembly, touches it, provided the  service is otherwise good or the
>   ball  is obstructed by the receiver or his/her partner;

Which means you must serve again if other than touching the net the service would be good.  other wise rule 2.10.1.1 would apply:

> 2.10 A Point
>
> 2.10.1 Unless the rally is a let, a  player shall score a point
>
> 2.10.1.1 if the opponent fails to make  a correct service

Comment: Not to cut down Greg's answer, which appears to be factually correct, you can't do better than citing the official rules.